# Installing Debian on USB

Tags: ubuntu, debian, usb, grub2

From my `Ubuntu`, I want to create a bootable `Debian` USB. I tried to install Debian with `debootstrap`. A brief list of commands is

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
debootstrap sid /mnt http://ftp.debian.org/debian
chroot /mnt
apt-get install linux-headers-3.2.0-4-686-pae linux-image-3.2.0-4-686-pae
apt-get install grub2
grub-install --recheck /dev/sdb
```

I have edited the `/mnt/etc/fstab` to include the `USB drive` with its `UUID`. But my problem is installing `grub` from within `chroot`, I get the following error

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for /boot/grub (is /dev mounted?).
```

I do not want to touch the grub of my `ubuntu` machine, I want to install the grub on my USB to be bootable on other machines.

What step/command I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind mount pseudo filesystems such as `/dev/` inside the chroot:

```
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc
```

Another option is to run grub-install from outside of the chroot, using `--root-directory`:

```
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdb
```

Comment: concise, informative, and complete!